# How to get snapshot metadata Firestore?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I need get snapshot metadata so can check if write to Firestore successful. I look at [source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/a6a469a0da9e90b83d957c2c612a994ff1c73adc/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/snapshot_metadata.dart) and see there is `SnapshotMetadata` and boolean `hasPendingWrites()`. But there is no example how to implement and I cannot find anywhere.

I need implement so can show in my chat app if message is sent or still sending.

My code:

```
            child: new FirestoreAnimatedList(
              query: Firestore.instance.collection('Collection')
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int x) {
                return new Chat(
                    snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
              },
            ),
```

I cannot find how get `SnapshotMetadata` in `query` and feed into `itemBuilder` so I can show `progressIndicator` if sending.

Anyone know solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Flutter may just have a wrapper on top of the existing scheme to request metadata updates. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for link! But doc example only use `.onSnapshot` / `.addSnapshotListener` to specify `includeMetadataChanges: true`. I need make sure I am get metadata when make query for `QuerySnapshot` above in my question. I am use `query` for `stream` not `addSnapshotListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You can show progress bar using `snapshot.connectionState`

```
if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
 return Text('Loading');
}
```

Comment: This not work. Cannot call `.connectionState` on `DocumentSnapshot`